# An example that a non-nilpotent matrix has a minimal polynomial of lower order than its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)$ of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and is of order $n$. By Hamilton-Cayley theorem $p_A(A)=O$. However, $p_A(x)$ might not be the monic polynomial $q(x)$ of lowest order s.t. $q(A)=O$. The lowest-order monic polynomial $q(x)$ s.t. $q(A)=O$ is called the minimal polynomial of $A$.

For example, an $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix $N$ s.t. $N^k=O,N^{k-1} \neq O$ and $k<n$ will have a minimal polynomial $q(x) = x^k$.

However, I am wondering if anyone can help give an example of a non-nipotent matrix whose minimal polynomial is of lower order than its characteristic polynomial. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest example is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. It's characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^n$, but the minimal polynomial is simply $x-1$ for any positive integer $n$.

Generalising slightly, this will happen for any scalar matrix, and this is never nilpotent unless the scalar is $0$ (when the matrix is defined over a field).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, take for example $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  2\end{bmatrix}.$$The characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^3$ and the minimal is $(x-2)^2$, as you can check.

Comment: This example illustrates how a *nilpotent* matrix whose minimal polynomial degree is less than its characteristic polynomial degree can be converted to a non-nilpotent instance by "shifting" (adding a multiple of the identity).

Comment: I actually wrote the matrix with zeroes instead of $2$'s in the diagonal first, but then I read the question again and saw the *non*-nilpotent. After the initial "oh crap" moment, I saw that fixing it was easy :)